# ANDROID - How to use a video as background in Andengine

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-webview, andengine, android-videoview

I'm using the game engine AndEngine in my app. I am using a variation of the AnalogOnScreenControls example found [here](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AnalogOnScreenControlsExample.java); I'm extending BaseGameActivity. I need to somehow set the background of the app to a video that I'm streaming from Ustream.com. I was thinking about making the background transparent, which I saw [here](http://code.google.com/p/andengineaugmentedrealityextension/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/extension/augmentedreality/BaseAugmentedRealityGameActivity.java), to display my .xml layout underneath with a WebView, but I could not figure out how to do it in my own code. This is what I tried (straight from the code in the second link) with the rest of my methods below it:

```
protected void onSetContentView() {
    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);  

    this.mRenderSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(new ComponentSizeChooser(4, 4, 4, 4, 16, 0)); 
    this.mRenderSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    this.mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(this.mEngine);

    this.setContentView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

}
```

I also tried setting the scene as a video, but could not do it. If anyone could provide help on making a streamed video my app background, while keeping the two analog controls fully functional and visible, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: did you got any solution to your problem ?

Comment: Have you got any lead to your problem...